# How to flatten tuple created using zip transformation in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, ipython, pyspark, rdd

I have two RDD's - RDD1 and RDD2 with following structure:

**RDD1:**

```
[(u'abc', 1.0), (u'cde', 1.0),....]
```

**RDD2:**

```
[3.0, 0.0,....]
```

Now I want to form a third RDD which values from each each index of the above two RDD's together. So the above output should become:

**RDD3:**

```
[(u'abc', 1.0,3.0), (u'cde', 1.0,0.0),....]
```

As you can see that values from RDD2 got added to tuples of RDD1. How can I do that? I tried to do `RDD3 = RDD1.map(lambda x:x).zip(RDD2)` but it produces this output - `[((u'abc', 1.0),3.0), ((u'cde', 1.0),0.0),....]` which is not what I want as you can see there's a separation between values of RDD1 and RDD2 by `()`.

**NOTE:** My RDD1 was formed using - `RDD1 = data.map(lambda x:(x[0])).zip(val)`

Comment: Use a subsequent map to create the tuples you want.

Comment: @Marcin I did `RDD3 = RDD1.map(lambda x:x).zip(RDD2)` like I have mentioned in my post above but that does not produce the desired output

Comment: *subsequent*; also your map is a no-op as it applies the identity transformation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply reshape your data after zipping:

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([(u'abc', 1.0), (u'cde', 1.0)])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([3.0, 0.0])

rdd1.zip(rdd2).map(lambda t: (t[0][0], t[0][1], t[1]))
```

In Python 2 it is possible to use:

```
rdd1.zip(rdd2).map(lambda ((x1, x2), y): (x1, x2, y))
```

but it is no longer supported in Python 3.

If you have more values to extract using indices may be tedious

```
lambda t: (t[0][0], t[0][1], t[0][2], ..., t[1]))
```

so you can experiment with something like this:

```
lambda t: tuple(list(t[0]) + [t[1]])
```

or implement a more sophisticated solution like here: [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2158395/1560062)